# remoteFunction call is not working grails

Tags: grails, drop-down-menu, grails-controller

I am trying to call a function once a selection is made in the drop down menu. Here is my code for the drop down menu in my list.gsp for the 'Code' domain class:

```
<td><g:select name="data" from="${codeInstance.datas.language}" 
          onchange="${remoteFunction(action: 'translationById')}"/> 
</td>
```

And here is the function I am trying to call. This is in my CodeController:

```
def translationById = {
        println "Fine"
        //println params;
    }
```

I am just trying to print out "Fine" so I know that the function was called, but "Fine" never gets printed. Why is the function not getting called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a closure, use a method, like:

```
def translationById() {
        println "Fine"
        //println params;
}
```

Also, use some browser debugger like firebug or similar to see if error message is being displayed.

What happens if you put an alert inside the onchange event instead of a remoteFunction? If the alert is displayed, then I think your problem is with the prototype library. Add the prototype library to your header. Like `<g:javascript library="prototype" />`.

Comment: i changed it from a closure to a method, and i am not getting any error message. It prints out "Fine" when I access it directly in the browser but not when I actually change the selection of the drop down menu

Comment: What happens if you put an alert inside the onchange event instead of a remoteFunction? If the alert is displayed, then I think your problem is with the prototype library. 


Add the prototype library to your header. Like <g:javascript library="prototype" />.

Comment: The alert is being displayed. Do i need the prototype library if I already have the jQuery plugin installed, I thought the jquery plugin was now the default javascript library used by grails

Comment: That's true if you got grails 2.0 or higher.

Comment: But what about your client code debugger? Do you have firebug or chrome developer's tools? What does it say when you change the options in your select?

Comment: yes i have grails 2.0.4, when I change the options in my select, the syntax appears correct in the chrome debugger for the new options added it shows up like so: 
  <select name=​"data" onchange=​"alert('Hi')​" id=​"data">​
   <option value=​"zxcv">​zxcv​</option>​
   </select>​

Comment: No, not with the alert (we know it is working). Put your old remoteFunction code back in it and change the option chosen in your select. Check if it warns you for any errors at the right side of the panel.

Comment: Yeah i am getting an error this is what i am getting:            Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined list:50
onchange

Comment: Hi tiago i got it to work, I had forgotten to add <g:javascript library="jquery" /> in my head, but I don't understand why i need to explicitly add that if the plugin is already installed?

Comment: There you go. The plugin is installed, you just need to say where you want to use it, that's what I think. I'll edit my answer and add that second comment, you can +1 if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks fine to me. Try to make sure that your 'codeInstance' and 'datas' are not null. Also, try and pass in the controller name like this:

```
remoteFunction(action: 'translationById', controller: 'code')
```

The new norm in grails is to use methods instead of closures:

```
def translationById(){
    println "fine"
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure they are not null since I am filling up the drop down box using the codeInstance's datas property, and the drop down box is getting correctly filled up. I specified the controller as well now, but it still is not working